# Dag created won't run, logs say "finished (failed) although the task says it's queued. (Info: None) Was the task killed externally?"

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am attempting to create a dag dynamically, dependant on a UUID variable. This dag is then to be run. This is how I am attempting to do it so far, but I am getting a few errors and am unsure on how to proceed:

The code to generate the dag is as follow:

```
def event_logic_runner(message: dict, **context) -> None:
    """
    Run logic to trigger another DAG.

    Parameters:
        message(str): Message to be passed as the configuration to the triggered DAG.
        **context: Additional context provided by Airflow.
    """
    if message:
        try:
            # Trigger the execution of another DAG with the provided configuration ('conf')
            dag_1 = generate_dag_1_from_template(message['UUID_var'])
            dag_bag = DagBag(collect_dags = True)
            dag_bag.bag_dag(dag=dag_1, root_dag=context['dag'])
            print(list(dag_bag.dags.keys()))
            dag_bag.sync_to_db()
            trigger_dag(dag_id=f'DAG_1_{message["UUID_var"]}', conf=message)

        except JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f'Error in Kafka message consumption: {e}')
    else:
        pass
```

And it creates and adds the dag exactly how I would expect it:
[Screenshot of DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROm6B.png)

The dag however is not being run. the first task immediately fails and returns this error:

```
[2024-02-07, 10:04:04 UTC] {scheduler_job_runner.py:781} ERROR - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: DAG_1_aedc2ejf-1111-455e-b3b3-1033f5798.initialisation manual__2024-02-07T10:03:25+00:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says it's queued. (Info: None) Was the task killed externally?
```

Upon further inspection, looking at the logs in the airflow directory, it gives back this message:

```
[2024-02-07T10:06:55.349+0000] {processor.py:161} INFO - Started process (PID=292591) to work on home/......../kafka_commander.py
[2024-02-07T10:06:55.351+0000] {processor.py:830} INFO - Processing file home/......../kafka_commander.py for tasks to queue
[2024-02-07T10:06:55.352+0000] {logging_mixin.py:188} INFO - [2024-02-07T10:06:55.351+0000] {dagbag.py:538} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from home/......../kafka_commander.py
[2024-02-07T10:06:55.366+0000] {processor.py:842} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from home/......../kafka_commander.py
[2024-02-07T10:06:55.371+0000] {processor.py:183} INFO - Processing home/......../kafka_commander.py took 0.025 seconds
```

The logs for the task where the dag is being created returns this:

```
[2024-02-07, 10:58:35 UTC] {dagbag.py:538} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/......../Airflow/Dags
[2024-02-07, 10:58:35 UTC] {dag.py:3033} INFO - Sync 4 DAGs
[2024-02-07, 10:58:35 UTC] {dag.py:3820} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for DAG_1_aedc2ejf-1111-455e-b3b3-1033f5798 to None, run_after=None
```

I'm completely stumped.

On another note, the dag only exists within the system for a short while before disappearing, I'm assuming this is due to the dagbag timeout variable in the config files but was wondering if anyone knew anyway to make it "live" until it was finished (assuming a working state).